# updateCamera() method results in error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working with this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/118225/introduction-sprite-kit-scene-editor

Working with the Xcode scene editor, I have attempted to add a camera object into the scene and then have that camera object stay centered on the player sprite at all times. This camera is supposed to update its position whenever the player sprite updates its position.  The function used to update the camera is:

```
func updateCamera() {
  if let camera = camera {
    camera.position = CGPoint(x: player!.position.x, y: player!.position.y)
  }
}
```

This method is only called when the scene initially loads and when the player sprite's position updates.  The error appears on the line that begins with "camera.position =" and appears instantly when the game is run.  The rest of the work with the camera that isn't in code is in the scene editor where the camera object is called "camera", starts out centered on the player sprite, and is set as the scene's camera.

Any help on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure `player` is not nil?  Are you sure that `player.position` is not nil?

Comment: @Putz1103 previously in the code, ` player ` is assigned the value of ' self.childNodeWithName("player") as? SKSpriteNode ' and is used throughout the code to update the player's position and to interact with the enemy sprites and other objects.  If you would like I can post all the code for the program as it isn't too long.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem to be that I had called the function `updateCamera` too early earlier in my code. I was calling it before `player` was given a value like @Putz1103 said so once I called the method after `player` had a value the method worked.